# Are names for organizations indeclinable or not?

Tags: грамматика, склонение

I have questions regarding the sentence: "I'm interested in Russian culture, especially in 'The Mighty Handful'".

1. Are names for organizations or groups like "Могучая кучка" indeclinable or not?
2. Would «Я заинтересован в русской культуре, особенно "Могучая кучка"» or «Я заинтересован в русской культуре, особенно "Могучей кучке"» be correct? Why is it dative case and not accusative (культуру)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, "***Я заинтересован в + Prepositional case***" ("в культуре" is actually Prepositional, not Dative) is a business term, that is, you are interested in something because you will get profit from it. The neutral way to translate "I'm interested in X" into Russian is:

> "***Я интересуюсь + Instrumental case***": Я интересуюсь культурой.

or

> "***Меня интересует + Nominative case***": Меня интересует культура.

Then, the names of artistic groups, associations and organizations are written in quotation marks and begin with a capital letter, like this: ***«Могучая кучка»***.

And, naturally, such names, like all the proper names, are declined. That is why your sentence can be translated into Russian in two ways:

> *Я интересуюсь русской культурой, особенно «Могучей кучкой».* — Both objects are in the Instrumental case.

or

> *Меня интересует русская культура, особенно «Могучая кучка».* — What was indirect objects becomes subjects here, in the Nominative case.

As you can see, the second variant is easier since no case adjustments are needed. While you are at a beginner level, I'd recommend to use that 2nd variant to say "I'm interested in X".

And remember, if a verb has two or more homogeneous objects, they must be in the same case, not the way you wrote it in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. A small question came up in my mind. Can I use different cases for the same object in one sentence, like for example "Я + something и меня + something", as long as I do not use the same verb  or does this sound wrong and I have to split the sentence into two separate sentences?

Comment: @Matriz - Yes, you can, if the sentence is compound, that is, having several subject-predicate threads. For example, your sentence from your question can be turned into a compound one: _Я интересуююсь русской культурой, [но] особенно меня интересует «Могучая кучка»._